# PHP Variable Passing not working in database call

Tags: php, mysql, parameter-passing

**This works.**

```
function get_distinct_size_for_bracelets() {
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT size FROM mytable WHERE id = 27 AND type='plastic' ORDER BY size";
}
```

**This does not work and stops php dead with no error reporting.**

```
 function get_distinct_size_for_bracelets($myvalue) {
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT size FROM mytable WHERE id = 27 AND type=".$myvalue." ORDER BY size";
}
```

I have tried a number of configurations and nothing is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function get_distinct_size_for_bracelets($myvalue) {
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT size FROM mytable WHERE id = 27 AND type='".$myvalue."' ORDER BY size";
}
```

You still need the single quotes in the SQL query.

Comment: Thanks. That was it. I have single quotes elsewhere in my database calls using arrays. So I don't know why this call would require a different syntax.

Comment: I think perhaps you've misunderstood the edit. If $myvalue was equal to "foo", using your original script, the SQL would have become "type=foo" and in SQL this means "type attribute is equal to foo attribute". With my edit, the SQL becomes "type='foo'" which means "type attribute equals the string 'foo'".

Answer (score 2):

Remember to quote the passed value:

```
function get_distinct_size_for_bracelets($myvalue) 
{ 
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT size FROM mytable WHERE id = 27 AND type=".$myvalue." ORDER BY size";
}
```

Should be:

```
function get_distinct_size_for_bracelets($myvalue) 
{ 
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT size FROM mytable WHERE id = 27 AND type='".$myvalue."' ORDER BY size";
}
```

Note the added single quotes at `type`.

Answer (score 2):

You need single quotes around it still. So

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT size FROM mytable WHERE id = 27 AND type='".$myvalue."' ORDER BY size";
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not escaping your value and you're forgetting your single quotes, that'd be my guess.  Try:

```
function get_distinct_size_for_bracelets($myvalue) { 
    $query = sprintf("SELECT DISTINCT size FROM mytable WHERE id = 27 AND type='%s'  ORDER BY size",
        mysql_real_escape_string($myvalue));
}
```

That lets you pass an escaped value into the string, as opposed to using concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
function get_distinct_size_for_bracelets($myvalue) {
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT size FROM mytable WHERE id = 27 AND type='".$myvalue."' ORDER BY size";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has different data types too. And [strings](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-syntax.html) need to be enclosed in quotes too:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT size FROM mytable WHERE id = 27 AND type='".$myvalue."' ORDER BY size";
```

Or better with additional use of the [`mysql_real_escape_string` function](http://docs.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string):

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT size FROM mytable WHERE id = 27 AND type='".mysql_real_escape_string($myvalue)."' ORDER BY size";
```